# Error output when using RLBigData class in R's RecordLinkage package

Tags: r, record-linkage

When using the R package `RecordLinkage`, some of the outputs following `epiClassify()` or `emClassify()` functions (which can operate on `RLBigDataLinkage`class objects) will output errors. These errors are not seen when I use the functions designed for smaller data comparisons, such as `compare.linkage()`. The documentation describing this can be found in the package vignettes [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/index.html).

My overall objective is to 'fuzzy match' data between two tables; once I know which rows are similar between the tables based on other variables, I can then use the index to grab unique IDs from the column in one table which are missing from the other table.

**Data**: This is some dummy data to reproduce the errors...

```
library(tibble)
table1 <- tibble(col1 = c("JIMMY", "SARA", "AYIL", "JIM", "JOHN"),
                 col2 = c("OHEARN", "HANDLE", "HASE", "JHORN", ""),
                 col3 = c("jdt322", "jdb122", "", "ddd532", "ddd444"))

table2 <- tibble(col1 = c("JIMMY", "SARAH", "SARA",  "AYIL", "JIM", "JOHN", "timm"),
                 col2 = c("OHEARN", "HAND","H",  "HASE", "JORN", "", ""),
                 col3 = c("jdt322", "jda122", "jdb112", "", "ddd532", "ddd444", "ddd322"))
```

When I use the above data in the functions for smaller comparisons, it works fine, without errors:

```
mypairs <- RecordLinkage::compare.linkage(table1, table2, strcmp = T)
mypairs_weights <- emWeights(mypairs)
result <- emClassify(mypairs_weights, threshold.lower = 1)
getTable(result)
summary(result)
getPairs(result, min.weight = 1)
```

However, after I use the `RLBigData` class (as in the code below), I get errors when:

- I try to access the object `result` after `emClassify()`: *Error in nrow(object@pairs) : 
  no slot of name "pairs" for this object of class "RLResult"*
- Trying to grab the summary with `summary(result)`: *Error in dbGetQuery(object@con, "select count(*) from data1") : 
  no slot of name "con" for this object of class "RLBigDataLinkage"*
- Trying to grab the comparison table with `getTable(result)`: *Error in table.ff(object@data@pairs$is_match, object@prediction, useNA = "ifany") : 
  Only vmodes integer currently allowed - are you sure ... contains only factors or integers?*
- Warnings are also thrown when first running the `RLBigDataLinkage()` function: *Warning messages:
  1: In result_fetch(res@ptr, n = n) :
  Don't need to call dbFetch() for statements, only for queries*

**The following code should reproduce these errors**

```
mypairs <- RLBigDataLinkage(table1, table2,
                            strcmp = T,
                            strcmpfun = "jarowinkler")

mypairs_weights <- emWeights(mypairs)
result <- emClassify(mypairs_weights, 0.6)
result
getTable(result)
summary(result)
getPairs(result, min.weight = 0.5)
```

I am not certain as to why the code spits these errors in the second case. I wanted to troubleshoot the code on a small dataset before moving onto larger datasets. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could shed light on these errors and warnings output by this package.